# Can the length of the cross product actually be negative?

Tags: proof-writing, cross-product, orientation

I'm trying to figure out why on earth the system of two vectors and their cross product must be positively oriented. Usually, this is just stated outright without further explanation.

I have however noticed that $||a x b||=||x||||y||sin \alpha $, which implies a somewhat strange solution to my problem. Since $ sin \alpha $ can be a negative value (for angles between 180 and 360 degrees) this would imply that $||a x b||$ could in fact be *negative* for those angles.

If by $||a x b||$ being positive we mean that it goes "up" from the plane and vice versa, this "would" in fact imply a positive orientation of the cross product and vectors a and b.

In that case the cross product vector would travel "upwards" from the plane if the angle was less than 180 degrees, making the entire triple of vectors positively oriented. It would travel "downwards" from the plane if the angle was between 180 and 360 degrees, but then we need only rotate the entire set of vectors 180 degrees and it would be plain that the system would still be positively oriented.

Am I onto something or am I grasping at straws?

Comment: The length of a vector is of course always non-negative.

Comment: The angle $\alpha$ is always between $0$ and $\pi$, inclusive. This is the angle between the sides $x$ and $y$ of the parallelogram, and it is *not* an oriented angle.

Comment: Then how is that formula even consistent? Since the sine of an angle can be negative this would mean that the formula would only be defined for angles between 0 and 180 degrees?

Comment: Following up on Ted's comment, look at the definition of $\alpha$ in whatever resource you are looking at. A careful treatment will specify how $\alpha$ is chosen, or at least give a diagram suggestive of the fact of how $\alpha$ is chosen.  When people don't mention this, they are relying on an "intuitive" understanding of angle of the sort that you could depict with your thumb and index finger (or a protractor), in which you always measure something at most 180 degrees. Or implicitly using absolute values noted in the answer below.

Comment: (Use `\times` to get a cross product symbol $\times$ rather than the letter $x$.)

Comment: There is a deeper thing related to this, yes. Are you familiar with the cross product in two dimensions, whose result is a real number? The "triple product" $(x \times y) \cdot z$?

Comment: @aschepler sadly no, I guess that must be related to the triple product expansion described as being 'very optional' at Khan Academy?  Will it help me get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct rule is $\Vert a\times b\Vert^2=\Vert a\Vert^2\Vert b\Vert^2\sin^2\alpha$, or equivalently $\Vert a\times b\Vert=\Vert a\Vert\Vert b\Vert|\sin\alpha|$ (note the $|\cdot|$ signs around $\sin\alpha$), because vectors cannot have negative length.